# How to change global values after an ActionEvent?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, global, actionevent

I want to increase the value of my counter to 10 when I click on a button. 
It works so far, but I don't know how to get the new counted value globally to
use it in other methods.

Here is a simple code:

```js
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
 
 public JTextPane textpane=new JTextPane();
 public JPanel panel;
 public JButton button = new JButton("count!");
 public static int counter=10;
 
 
    Test() {       
     addListener();     
        panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(textpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);        
        createFrame();
    }
    
    private void addListener() {
     button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {             
             counter=counter+10;
             textpane.setText("counter is set to -> "+counter);
            }            
        }); 
     System.out.println("new value >> "+counter);     
    }
    
    private void createFrame()  {
     JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) { new Test(); }
}
```

How can I get the new counter value globally?

Comment: By globally, do you mean in other classes? Because to access the static variable `counter` from other classes you can just (in this case) use `Test.counter`.

Comment: no, I mean other methods. After changing the counter value by clicking on the button I want to use the new calculated value for other operations in another method in the same class. But I don't know how to get the new value from the listener

Comment: Well the value doesn't exist in the listener, it exists in the class 'Test'. If you are using another method in the same class, you can use the variable 'counter' just by saying 'counter'. If, for instance, you want to add a 'doubleCounter()' method, all you have to put in the method is 'counter = counter*2;' & that's all you need to access or modify the variable.